# Need Clarification on Recursive Function Methodology

Tags: c, cs50

Apologies in advance, I am very new to c and programming.

I'm currently working on understanding how recursive functions work and have a major mental block.

I was provided an example of a recursive function that creates a "pyramid" of sorts out of hash symbols (see below).  I can't understand why the output is not flipped horizontally, with n hashes on top and 1 hash on bottom.

In trying to make sense of it, I created a table with the number of loops, n value, n - 1 value, and how man hashes I think it should print.

[image]

On loop 1, n starts out as 4 and the "for loop" should run 4 times since "i" goes through during 0, 1, 2, and 3.

Line break

On loop 2, n is now 3 and the "for loop" should run 3 times since "i" goes through during 0, 1, and 2.

And so on and so forth...

I created nested for loops that I thought would provide the same result: n (height) is 4 originally and works down to 0, i works upwards from 0 printing hashes but the result is the exact opposite.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void draw(int n);

int main(void)
{
    // prompt user for height of pyramid
    int height = get_int("Height ");

    // call recursive 'draw' function
    draw(height);

    printf("\n");

    // my nested loop function I made that I can't tell how is different from the recursive function
    for (int n = height; n >= 0; n--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// recursive function example I was given that I cannot make sense of
void draw(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    draw(n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            printf("#");
    }

printf("\n");
}
```

Result below.  Their result on top.  Mine below it.

[image]

If someone could please help clarify what I'm missing I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In draw function move draw(n-1) after the loop and see what happens. (Spoiler: it will do the same things as your for loop). Recursion is just calling a function from itself with other parameter values. End of recursion is usually made by a test to return from the function. Add some print in your code to understand where it goes so .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called the `draw(n-1);` before the for loop. Therefore the function recursively called like this.

First `Draw(4);` function calls from main function. Then calls `Draw(4-1); -> Draw(3);`  Then again `Draw(3-1); -> Draw(2);` it doesn’t go to the line which has for loop until base condition. So, next again calls `Draw(2-1); -> Draw(1);`
After that `Draw(1-1); -> Draw(0);` since n=0 function will return.

Next go backwards now. Because you haven’t completed the Draw(n) function. You only did recursively calling it self. After finishing that you have printing part. Since you are now in `Draw(1)`, you starts printing from 1. You came to `Draw(1)` from `Draw(4)`. So now you have to go again back to `Draw(4)` from `Draw(1)`. That’s why we go backwards.

Path explanation:

Now you are in Draw(1); so it prints `#`. Then finishes Draw(1); next `Draw(2);` so it prints `##`. next `Draw(3);` so it prints `###`.
next `Draw(4);` so it prints `####` .

That’s how the recursion function works. Therefore the output is,

```
#
##
###
####
```

In your nested loop it starts from 4. Because you have used `n=height`. So your code should start from n=1 like below code.

```
for (int n = 1; n <= height ; n++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look to see when this recursion will emit its first out put

```
void draw(int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    draw(n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            printf("#");
    }

printf("\n");
}
```

see that it keeps calling itself *before* the `printf`, it only stops doing that one n reaches 0, then it starts returning and calling the prints, but in reverse order of n.

ie it goes

```
 draw(4)->draw(3)->draw(2)->draw(1)->draw(0)
                            printf loop *1
                   printf loop * 2
          printf loop * 3
 printf loop * 4
```

Comment: Hi @pm100, thank you for the reply.  I guess what I'm still not understanding, even after reading your response multiple times, is why it calls the print statements in reverse order of n.  I'm sure it will suddenly "click" but I'm really having trouble understanding why.

Comment: @Quinn don't read the code. Execute it dumbly in your mind line by line